# Simulate HTML5 LocalStorage in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, local-storage

I am making a bot to scrap and extract data from web pages. Some websites require cookies, they save some specific sata in the client's cookies to verify it in every request, for security reasons. Now i got stuck with a new type of measure in which the website keeps the same idea, but instead of using cookies, it uses HTML5 LocalStorage.
So my question is, is there any know way to simulate LocalStorage read/write, if not, is there any idea to do it?

my first thought is to parse the javascript code that uses the LocalStorage and handle read/writes in php variables, this would work at least for some basic known operations.

Comment: Can you execute JavaScript with your bot?

Comment: no, i thought of making a list of known operations, but not just any javascript code

Comment: That won't work. If you want to support JavaScript-powered pages you'll most likely need something like nodejs' JSDom so you can actually run the javascript on a site. However, I don't think there are many sites that REQUIRE LocalStorage and don't work at all with just cookies and no JavaScript... and even search engines like google simply don't support most javascript-only sites.

Comment: anyone tried this? http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

Comment: @JacerOmri I've never used this extension, but V8 (the underlying library) doesn't have any DOM-related capabilities (only pure ECMAScript).

Comment: @ComFreek can't php's own DOM extension compensate this?

Comment: @JacerOmri No, it only parses the XML or HTML thus you only get a tree of XML/HTML tags.

Comment: @ComFreek yes, we can locate <script> tags and reparse query selectors, at least. Would that be enough? (i'm acting desperate lol)

Comment: @JacerOmri About which query selectors are you talking? You could run regular expressions over the JS, but that would only be a suboptimal solution. The site owners can just change his code and your code will stop working. (BTW do you know that scraping websites and showing the data is illegal, at least in some countries?)

Comment: @ComFreek you are right, i'm in Tunisia, everything is legal here. In my last comment i was talking about php's DOM Extension